# Mapping every URL that has no file extension to a sub-path in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, web, spring-boot

I have the following web app layout:

```
/webapp
    /pathA
        /index.jsp
        /style.css
    /pathB
        /pathB1
            /index.jsp
    ...
    /pathX
        /index.jsp
```

How can I create a mapping in [**Spring Boot**](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) such as:

- `/pathA` maps to `/pathA/index.jsp`,
- `/pathB/pathB1` maps to `/pathB/pathB1/index.jsp`
- etc.

Essentially, any URI that has no file extension specified (e.g. `/pathA/style.css` should be excluded from this mapping) should be redirected to an URI that has `index.jsp` appended. I'd like to apply the mapping as a general rule, so I don't have to specify every possible path that should be mapped like this.

Comment: Use a Servlet Filter